# Improving Code when using lots of nested statements in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, nested

I started using Python 3 recently after some courses on Matlab (which focussed mainly on using mathematical calculations and plots) and I am still very much a beginner.
However I thought it would be fun to create a calculator that calculates the amount of pokemon you can evolve with the available candy in Pokemon go with the use of Tkinter for the GUI. The program works fine and gives good results. However, I am trying to improve my coding and this code includes a lot of nested if and while statements, amongst other extensive variable and parameter use. I was wondering how this code can be improved to be more 'pythonic' or if this the correct way of creating a program like this. 
Thank you in advance

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import messagebox


    def EvolveCalc():
        title = "Pokemon evolve calculator"
        Poke = var.get()
        Candies_total = Candies.get()
        PAmount = Poke_amount.get()
        if Poke == 'Pokemon':
            messagebox.showinfo(title,
                        "Please select a Pokemon from the dropdown menu")
        elif not PAmount.isdigit():
            messagebox.showinfo(title, "Please only enter numbers")
        elif not Candies_total.isdigit():
            messagebox.showinfo(title, "Please only enter numbers")
        else:
            Candies_total = int(Candies.get())
            PAmount = int(Poke_amount.get())
            Evolve = int((Candies_total - 1) / (Pokedex[Poke] - 1))
            Candies_needed = (PAmount * (Pokedex[Poke] - 1)) + 1
            if PAmount < Evolve:
                n = 0
                while Candies_needed <= Candies_total:
                    n = n + 1
                    PAmount = PAmount + 1
                    Candies_needed = ((PAmount) * (Pokedex[Poke] - 1)) + 1
                    Candies_total = Candies_total + 3
                    Evolve2 = int((Candies_total - 1) / (Pokedex[Poke] - 1))
                String1 = '''You have enough candies too evolve {0} {1},
                but you only have {2} {1} in storage and thus can only
                evolve {2} {1} If you catch {3} more {1} you can now
                evolve {4} {1}.'''
                messagebox.showinfo(title, String1.format(Evolve, Poke,
                                                          Poke_amount.get(),
                                                          n, Evolve2))
            else:
                m = 0
                while Candies_total <= Candies_needed:
                    m = m + 1
                    PAmount = PAmount - 1
                    Candies_needed = ((PAmount) * (Pokedex[Poke] - 1)) + 1
                    Candies_total = Candies_total + 1
                    Evolve2 = int((Candies_total - 1) / (Pokedex[Poke] - 1))
                String2 = 'Transfer {0} {1} so you can evolve a total of {2} {1}.'
                messagebox.showinfo(title, String2.format(m, Poke, Evolve2))


    root = Tk()

    Pokedex = {'pidgey': 12,
               'caterpie': 12,
               'weedle': 12
               }

    root.title("Pokemon evolve calculator")

    var = StringVar(root)
    var.set('Pokemon')
    choices = Pokedex.keys()
    Pokemon = OptionMenu(root, var, *choices)
    Pokemon.grid(column=0, row=1)

    L1 = Label(root, text='Candies')
    L1.grid(column=1, row=0)

    Candies = Entry(root)
    Candies.grid(column=1, row=1)

    L2 = Label(root, text='Pokemon amount in storage')
    L2.grid(column=2, row=0)

    Poke_amount = Entry(root)
    Poke_amount.grid(column=2, row=1)

    Calculate = Button(root, text='Calculate', command=EvolveCalc)
    Calculate.grid(column=1, row=2)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This question might be better suited at the [code review stack exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use lowercase and underscore delimited functions so `EvolveCalc` would be `evolve_calc`
2. Use lowercase and readable variables so `Poke` and `Candies_total` would become `poke` and `total_candies`
3. This piece of code can be reduced

   ```
   elif not PAmount.isdigit():
        messagebox.showinfo(title, "Please only enter numbers")
   elif not Candies_total.isdigit():
       messagebox.showinfo(title, "Please only enter numbers")
   ```

   to

   ```
   elif not PAmount.isdigit() or not Candies_total.isdigit():
       messagebox.showinfo(title, "Please only enter numbers")
   ```
4. Your `Pokedex` can be formatted so it's more readable

   ```
   Pokedex = {'pidgey': 12,
              'caterpie': 12,
              'weedle': 12
              }
   ```

   to

   ```
   Pokedex = {
     'pidgey': 12,
     'caterpie': 12,
     'weedle': 12
   }
   ```
5. I cannot run your code because it's not formatted correctly. The spaces are off after your first `else` block finishes.

Additional suggestions:

- read PEP8
- look over code examples
- write small reusable code containerized in functions
- add comments to explain some of your math

Comment: Thank you for your comment and suggestions. I adjusted the code so you should be able to run it if your interested. Replacing for intstance the else block with a function would mean putting that function outside of the main function and calling it from within the main function? Experimenting with this earlier gave me trouble, because the variables are not global by definition in python and since i update the variables in the while loops constantly I would have to redefine each variable every time right? Sorry if that sounds confusing.